# Can plotly(python) slider start static (without animation) in html file?

Tags: python, html, plotly, slider, plotly-python

I have been trying to create a plotly figure (scatter plot) with a date slider and then exporting the figure to an HTML file.

To do so I have used the plotly px library: `px.scatter(animation_frame...)`, just as in the second example here: https://plotly.com/python/sliders/.

Once I have the figure I save it to a HTML file with `fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn')`.
This does work, but the problem I face is that the slider starts animating the frames by default whenever I open the html file. Is there a way to make the slider start static by default? I need it to start static because the figure has many frames and the slider automatically updating the frames makes the file really slow.

My code is:

```
figDVTO = px.scatter(dfPrueba, x="DíasVencimiento", y="Inflación", labels=dict(DíasVencimiento="Días al Vencimiento", Inflación="Inflación Implícita (%)"), 
                animation_frame="Fecha", title="Curva Inflación Implícita Diaria", range_y=[1, 8], 
                range_x=[0,7000], color = "Implícita", color_discrete_map = dicColores)


figDVTO.update_traces(marker=dict(size=12, line=dict(width=2,
                                                        color='DarkSlateGrey')),
                                                        selector=dict(mode='markers'))
```

I tried to set the "stop" animation button as default, but even when I do so, the slider animates the frames.

I also tried to construct the figure with plotly.graph_objects Figure, by constructing the dictionary that contains the frames.

I am able to recreate the figure I create with plotly express. However, after looking in plotly´s documentation I´m still no sure how to make the slider initially static. Have tried changing the method in updatemenus, as well as changing the method in sliders, but nothing seems to work.

I would really appreciate any sort of help, been scratching my head for weeks now...

Here is my complete code to construct the figure with plotly.graph_objects:

```
# make figure
fig_dict = {
    "data": [],
    "frames": [],
    "layout": {'legend': {'title': {'text': 'Implícita'}, 'tracegroupgap': 0},
                'sliders': [{
                            'active': 0,
                            'currentvalue': {'prefix': 'Fecha='},
                            'len': 0.9,
                            'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 60},
                            'steps':[],
                            'x': 0.1,
                            'xanchor': 'left',
                            'y': 0,
                            'yanchor': 'top'
                }],
                'title': {'text': 'Curva Inflación Implícita Diaria',
                          'font':dict(
                                        family="Arial",
                                        size=18,
                                    )
                },
                'updatemenus': [{'active': 0,
                                'bgcolor': '#B0BEC5',
                                'buttons': [{'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration':
                                                      500, 'redraw': False},
                                                      'mode': 'immediate',
                                                      'fromcurrent': True,
                                                      'transition': {'duration':
                                                      500, 'easing': 'linear'}}],
                                             'label': '&#9654;',
                                             'method': 'animate'},
                                            {'args': [[None], {'frame':
                                                      {'duration': 0, 'redraw':
                                                      False}, 'mode': 'immediate',
                                                      'fromcurrent': True,
                                                      'transition': {'duration': 0,
                                                      'easing': 'linear'}}],
                                             'label': '&#9724;',
                                             'method': 'animate'}],
                                'direction': 'left',
                                'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 70},
                                'showactive': True,
                                'type': 'buttons',
                                'x': 0.1,
                                'xanchor': 'right',
                                'y': 0,
                                'yanchor': 'top'}],
                'xaxis': {'anchor': 'y',
                         'domain': [0.0, 1.0],
                         'range': [0, 7000],
                         'title': {'text': 'Días al Vencimiento'}},
               'yaxis': {'anchor': 'x',
                         'domain': [0.0, 1.0],
                         'range': [1, 8],
                         'title': {'text': 'Inflación Implícita (%)'}}
                }
}

#Creating starting frame
listFechas = list(dfPrueba['Fecha'].unique())
listImplicitas = list(dfPrueba['Implícita'].unique())

fecha=listFechas[0]
for implicita in listImplicitas:
    data_dict = {
        "x": np.array(dfPrueba.loc[(dfPrueba['Fecha']==fecha)&(dfPrueba['Implícita']==implicita), 'DíasVencimiento']),
        "y": np.array(dfPrueba.loc[(dfPrueba['Fecha']==fecha)&(dfPrueba['Implícita']==implicita), 'Inflación']),
        'legendgroup': str(implicita),
        'hovertemplate': ('Implícita='+ str(implicita)+'<br>Fecha='+str(fecha)+'<br>Días al Vencimiento=%{x}<br>Inflación Implícita (%)=%{y}<extra></extra>'),
        'marker': {'color': dicColores[implicita], 'line': {'color': 'DarkSlateGrey', 'width': 2}, 'size': 12, 'symbol': 'circle'},
        "mode": "markers",
        'marker': {'color': dicColores[implicita], 'line': {'color': 'DarkSlateGrey', 'width': 2}, 'size': 12, 'symbol': 'circle'},
        "name": str(implicita),
        'orientation': 'v',
        'showlegend': True,
        'type': 'scatter',
        'xaxis': 'x',
        'yaxis': 'y',
    }
    fig_dict["data"].append(data_dict)

# make frames
for fecha in listFechas:
    frame = {"data": [], "name": str(fecha)}
    for implicita in listImplicitas:
        data_dict = {
            "x": np.array(dfPrueba.loc[(dfPrueba['Fecha']==fecha)&(dfPrueba['Implícita']==implicita), 'DíasVencimiento']),
            "y": np.array(dfPrueba.loc[(dfPrueba['Fecha']==fecha)&(dfPrueba['Implícita']==implicita), 'Inflación']),
            'legendgroup': str(implicita),
            'hovertemplate': ('Implícita='+ str(implicita)+'<br>Fecha='+str(fecha)+'<br>Días al Vencimiento=%{x}<br>Inflación Implícita (%)=%{y}<extra></extra>'),
            'marker': {'color': dicColores[implicita], 'line': {'color': 'DarkSlateGrey', 'width': 2}, 'size': 12, 'symbol': 'circle'},
            "mode": "markers",
            'marker': {'color': dicColores[implicita], 'line': {'color': 'DarkSlateGrey', 'width': 2}, 'size': 12, 'symbol': 'circle'},
            "name": str(implicita),
            'orientation': 'v',
            'legendgroup': '23',
            'showlegend': True,
            'type': 'scatter',
            'xaxis': 'x',
            'yaxis': 'y'
        }
        frame["data"].append(data_dict)

    fig_dict["frames"].append(frame)

#Updating sliders steps

for fecha in listFechas:
    loop_dic={'args': [[str(fecha)], {'frame':
                                        {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False},
                                        'mode': 'immediate', 'fromcurrent':
                                        True, 'transition': {'duration': 0,
                                        'easing': 'linear'}}],
                                       'label': str(fecha),
                                       'method': 'animate'}
    
    fig_dict["layout"]["sliders"][0]["steps"].append(loop_dic)

#Creating figure 
figB = go.Figure(fig_dict)

figB.update_layout(
    title="Curva Inflación Implícita Diaria",
    xaxis_title="Días al Vencimiento",
    yaxis_title="Inflación Implícita (%)",
    legend_title="Serie",
    font=dict(
        family="Arial",
        size=18,
    ),
    hovermode="x",
    yaxis=dict(tickformat=".2f")
)
```